# Will (be) flourish(ed)

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, passive-voice

It seems that the sentence "*A young mind **will flourish** with the proper guidance*" could be rewritten as "*A young mind **will be flourished** with the proper guidance*" without major difference in meaning. Are these two sentences equal? If they are, is there any rule for such a situation?

Comment: They are not equal. I can't think of why off the top of my head, but #2 is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "flourish" in the sense of prosper is an intransitive verb:  it doesn't take an object.  It thus cannot be transposed into the passive voice

"Flourish" has another meaning, to wave about, and in this sense it is transitive.  So in the active voice, you can say

> The bullfighter (subject)   flourished (active verb)   a cape (direct object).

To transpose this into the passive, make the direct object the new subject, make the new verb passive with a form of the verb "to be" as an auxiliary with the old verb; make the old subject the object of the preposition "by":

A cape (subject)   was flourished (passive verb)   by the bullfighter.

Comment: What about such sentences: "*His life **will be flourished** with wealth and luxuries and he will lead a happy and peaceful life.*"

Answer (score 1):

"flourish" (in the sense you use it, i.e., to grow and prosper)  is an **intransitive** verb.  Such verbs cannot be used in passive tense, as they do not take a direct object.

http://i.word.com/idictionary/flourish

Answer (score 0):

"will be flourished" is extremely stilted at best and probbaly gramatically wrong at worst. By changing the to passive voice you imply that someone else will perform the "flourishing" which doesn't make much sense as it is the "mind" that flourishes. You can't in general perform the flourishing externally it is an internal process of whatever is flourishing.

You could say "will be made to flourish" but that has a different meaning implying a more proactive approach to ensuring the mind flourishes.

Edit: I just realised one case where you might use "will be flourished". In case you are using the sense of flourish "To make bold, sweeping movements" I suppose you could say "The flags will be flourished by the flag bearers at that time." It still sounds really odd to me though.